# django terminate adding any input to the database from the form

Tags: python, html, django, web, backend

In an auction web. I'm trying to terminate adding any input (bids, comments and add to watchlist) by any user to the database if the owner of the product press on 'close ' button so I tried to implement this pseudo code:
in views.py

```
function listing:
t = 1
if t == 1:
   if owner clicks on the close button:
      ...
      t = 2
   if the user adds a comment:
      ...
   if the user adds a bid:
      ...
   if user clicks on add to watchlist button:
      ...
else:
    return message ('Auction has ended')
```

I have implemented this code and the listing page accepted entries and inputs after the owner of the listing clicked on the 'close' button. I also tried to change the value of t to a boolean value ( t = True, if t == True, if user clicked: return t = False) but it didn't work. so what is the problem.

```
def entry(request, name):
    enter = listing.objects.get(title = name)
    f= bids.objects.filter(product_id = enter)
    x = 0 
    z = ""
    last = None
    ended = None
    like = "k"
    t = 1
    if t == 1:
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("bid"):
                biddd = int(request.POST['bid'])
                user = request.user
                if biddd > x:
                    bids.objects.create(bid= biddd , product_id= listing.objects.get(title = name).id, user = user)
        for object in f:
            if object.bid > x:
                if object.bid > x:
                    x = object.bid

        if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('close_bid'):
            final = listing.objects.get(title = name)
            last = bids.objects.get(bid = x, product = final).user
            t = 2
        
        elif request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("bid"):
                bidd = int(request.POST['bid'])
                if bidd >= x:
                    messages.info(request, 'bid accepted')
                    z = "#0a720e"
                else:
                    messages.info(request, 'bid already present')
                    z = "#f44336"

        elif request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("watchlist"):
                if request.user.is_authenticated:
                    productt = listing.objects.get(title = name)
                    user = request.user 
                    exist = watchlist.objects.filter(product = productt, user = user)
                    if exist.exists():
                        messages.info(request, 'Already added to your watchlist')
                    else:
                        watchlist.objects.create(product = productt, user = user)
                else:
                    return render(request, "auctions/login.html")
                

        elif request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("comments"):
                if request.user.is_authenticated:
                    comment = request.POST['comments']
                    product = listing.objects.get(title = name)
                    user = request.user
                    comments.objects.create(comment = comment, user = user, product = product)
                else:
                    return render(request, "auctions/login.html")

        commentproduct =  listing.objects.get(title = name)
        commentss= comments.objects.filter( product = commentproduct)
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Auction has ended')
    return render(request, "auctions/entry.html" , {"enter":enter, "bid": f, "x": x, "z":z, "comments":commentss, "winner": last, "ended": ended, "l": l})
```

in entry.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}


<h1>Listing: {{enter}}</h1>
<img src="{{enter.image}}">
<p>{{enter.description}}</p>
<h3>Current Bid: {{x}}</h3>
<form action = "#" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Add bid:</label>
    <input type="number" name="bid">
    <input type="submit">
</form>



{% for message in messages %}
<div class="alert" style="background-color:{{z}}">
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
    {{message}}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}

<form method='POST' action='#'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="watchlist" value="Add to watchlist">&nbsp;Add to watchlist</button>
</form>
{% for message in messages %}
<h5>{{message}}</h5>
{% endfor %}

<h2>Details:</h2>
<p><strong>Owner:</strong> {{enter.author}}</p>
<p><strong>Category:</strong> {{enter.category}}</p>

<br>
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<form method="POST" action="#">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Add a comment" style="width:600px"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Add comment">
</form>

{% if user.is_authenticated and user == enter.author %}
<form method='POST' action='#'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit" name="close_bid" value="Close bid">&nbsp;Close Bid</button>
</form>
{% endif %}



<h2>Comments:</h2>
{% for comment in comments %}
<h3>{{comment.user}}:</h3>
<p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
{% endfor %}


{% if user.is_authenticated and user == winner  %}
<div class="alert" style="background-color:green">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
  You won!
</div>
{% elif not user.is_authenticated %} 
<p></p>
{% else %}
<div class="alert" style="background-color:red">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
  You lost!
</div>
{% endif %}



{% if user.is_authenticated and user == winner %}
<p>
  You won!
</p>
{% elif not user.is_authenticated %} 
<p>.</p>
{% else %}
<p>you lost</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Even in pseudo code `if == 1:` make no sense.

Comment: @RedCricket Sorry, It was a typing error and I corrected it